# Network Profile "Top Answers" showing deleted posts

Tags: bug, network-profile, deleted-posts

On [my network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/186761/tzhx), under the "Top Answers" heading there is a link to a question I answered titled "[What do we call to “non-programmers” ? ( Like “muggle” in HP )](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46614/what-do-we-call-to-non-programmers-like-muggle-in-hp/46627#46627)".

This question/answer pair has been deleted for quite some time and so I wouldn't expect it to appear in this list, as for most people (but some reason not me?) clicking it would return a 404.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the network profile is not synchronized. Lots of reports about it. Bug indeed.

Comment: @Shadow I tried searching but couldn't find a duplicate issue; sorry.

Comment: Well, no exact dupe actually. Existing reports are about comments and wrong score. Likely same cause, but I won't close over this.

Comment: Same problem with my (deleted) answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382129/an-account-or-cash-hoard-for-regular-expenses/382135#382135) (currently on the 2nd page with a score of 24).

Comment: This happens on my network profile too. My [third most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428921/4284627) is to a deleted question, but it's still shown in my network profile.

Comment: Still an issue. [Here](https://stackexchange.com/users/10108030), top two answers were deleted for moderation reasons, but still showing up.