# Posts Removed as Spam Still Appear in Network Profile

Tags: support, bug, spam, network-profile, deleted-posts

I know it is quite likely that this post is a duplicate of [Question still appears in my top network posts even after having it disassociated from my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258170) at least with regard to how these posts are handled. However, I was made aware of [this network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/84178/null-pointer) which currently lists 3 posts under "Top Answers":

[image: Top Answers showing three Stack Overflow answers scoring 7, 5, and 5 respectively]

All three of which ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995525), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935835), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1959863)) were deleted with a red-flag on Apr 16, 2011.

The primary reasons for this question are:

1. The linked post *only* addresses disassociated questions and not Spam or R/A posts
2. To confirm that these posts remain on the network profile because they were removed prior to the implementation of some system which now removes red-flagged posts from the network profile
3. To get clarification that the correct procedure to have red-flagged posts removed from a network profile is, in fact, the contact form as suggested [the answer on the linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367799).

---

As a follow up to the discussion in the comments on [that answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367799), it seems that the primary reason why disassociated posts cannot be automatically removed from network profiles retroactively is due to the fact that [disassociations are not recorded in a way that facilitates doing things with them programatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1225610). However, I would also like to revisit that conversation in case that spam/R/A posts are tracked in a way which would make purging them possible.

I am aware that this is likely something that affects a very small population of users and it may even be possible that this particular account has just had no updates to their network profile due to inactivity and if this were a more active user it may have been handled automatically. However, leaving these posts visible on the network profile contrasts with the way that red-flagged content is handled in general. All penalties associated with having a post red-flagged are shown only to moderators and by leaving these on the network profile it effectively undermines that protection.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this: You ask and get a post dissociated from your account; but the link is still shown in your network profile?

Comment: That seems to be an accurate summary of [the linked MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258170/1099857), but not this question which is about red-flagged posts in the network profile. @bad_coder

Comment: I doubt it's related to the spam deletion itself. We have countless reports of deleted posts not propagating to the network profile that have never been looked into. Removing deleted posts from those lists has been unreliable for a long time and is probably still an active issue today.

Comment: Related (likely duplicate) posts: [Network Profile "Top Answers" showing deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324814/348196), [In the top answers list on my network profile, an answer deleted five years ago shows up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369167/348196)